# Android ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream always returns null

Tags: android, photo, contacts

I've searched all the ways of doing this and none works, here is my code:

```
public static Bitmap loadContactPhoto(ContentResolver cr, long id) {
    Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
            ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, id);
    InputStream input = ContactsContract.Contacts
            .openContactPhotoInputStream(cr, uri);
    // InputStream input = ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo
    if (input == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
 }
```

I do have

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

in my manifest. Spent two days on this, it is probably really stupid but I can't find it.

Comment: This is called from my main activity

Answer (score 1):

Weird, I was able to make it work by using the photo parsed URI (removed the /photo):

```
        photoURIs = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_URI));
        photoURIs = photoURIs.substring(0, photoURIs.length() - 6); // remove /photo
        photoURI = Uri.parse(photoURIs);
```

Photo URI:   content://com.android.contacts/contacts/107/photo

Content URI: content://com.android.contacts/contacts/501

I still don't understand why the ID would be differents